# Please help newbie with IE7 layout float glitch

Tags: html, css, layout, internet-explorer-7, css-float

I'm pretty new to web design and need a little help. I designed the website mostly using the 960.gs CSS framework except I used some floats in the header and the header is now giving me some problems in IE7 (and IE6 but I'm not going to bother with IE6).

The problem lies with the H1 which is my logo (image replacement used) which has moved up and the nav ul which has moved from where its supposed to be floated right to the left.

Can anyone please tell me how to fix the following code for the header so it works in IE7?

**HTML**

```
  <div class="intro">

    <div class="container_12">


           <header>

            <div class="meta_bar">
                <ul>
                    <li><span>Free Quote:</span></li>
                    <li id="phone">444-444-4444</li>
                    <li id="email"><a href="mailto:someone@example.com?Subject=Information%20Request">info@example.com</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <h1><a href="index.html">ExampleCompany</a></h1>

            <nav>

                <ul>
                    <li class="selected"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li class=""><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
                    <li class=""><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                    <li class=""><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>

            </nav>

            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit integer in elit orci, a eleifend velit.
            </p>

        </header>

       </div><!--end header container-->

 </div><!--end intro-->
```

**CSS**

```
.intro {
   border-top: 10px solid black;
}

.meta_bar {
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #8e8e8e;
    padding-top: 24px;
    float: right;
}

.meta_bar span {
    font-size: 11px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.meta_bar li {
    display: inline;
    margin-left: 0.5em;
    padding-left: 1.5em;
}

.meta_bar a {
    color: #8e8e8e;
}

#phone {
    background: url(../img/phone.png) no-repeat left center;
}

#email {
    background: url(../img/email.png) no-repeat left center;
}

header {
    padding: 0 10px;
}

header h1 {
    float: left;
    clear: both;
    padding: 12px 0 20px 0;
    }

header h1 a {
    width: 228px;
    height: 65px;
    display: block;
    background: url(../img/sprite.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
    text-indent: -9999%;
    }

nav {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 36px;
}

nav li {
    display: inline;
    margin: 0 0 0 20px;
}

nav a {
    font-size: 14px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}

nav a:hover {
    color: #e8960b;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.selected a {
    color: #e8960b;
}

header p {
    clear: both;
    border-top: 2px dashed #8e8e8e;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Garamond, “Hoefler Text”, Times New Roman, Times, serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 22px 0 22px 0;
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Wrap you h1 tag inside a `<div>` tag and give your div tag all your stylings. That should fix the issue.

Comment: Hmm... I put the h1 in a div with the class of "logo" and then used following CSS:

Comment: .logo {
 float: left;
 clear: both;
 padding: 12px 0 20px 0;
 }

Comment: I found the solution. Instead of using clear:both to get the h1 to clear the meta_bar div I just put the meta_bar div in a grid_12 div (a full width div) and then removed the clear:both from CSS.